# cannot use PUDB python debugger after CANOPY installation

Tags: python, macos, unix

I've previously used pudb for python debugging with no problem however after installing Canopy I now get a message

```
no module named pudb
```

thats when trying to run it using

```
python -m pudb.run ./my_prog.py
```

I tried a reinstall using

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pudb
```

which appeared to execute correctly but I still get the same error.

I'm assuming its something to do with virtual environments but I don't know how to get around it. I'm looking to try out canopy so didn't want to uninstall it but would like to know how to switch in/out of its env and also ideally not have it as my default.

thanks